# How to show the hierarchy of an XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I want to traverse from child node to parent and vice versa. Can someone please tell me how can I achieve this using C#?

If my input is Disney World, output should be Orlando - Florida - United States - World
If my input is CME Group, outputs should be Chicago - Illinois - United States - World
Bangalore - Karnataka - India - World
Parent to child traversing
If my input is United Kingdom, outputs should be London - Big Ben - Heathrow - Westminster
Manchester - Old Trafford
If my input is Pune, output should be “No children found”

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<World >
  
    <Level1 name="United States">
      <Level2 name="Florida">
        <Level3 name="Miami">
          <Level4 name="Ft.Lauderdale"/>
          <Level4 name="Palm Beach"/>
          <Level4 name="South Beach">
            <Level5 name="Mangos"/>
          </Level4>
        </Level3>
        <Level3 name="Tampa"/>

        <Level3 name="Orlando">
          <Level4 name="Oak Ridge"/>
          <Level4 name="Disney World"/>
        </Level3>

      </Level2>
      <Level2 name="Illinois">
        <Level3 name="Chicago">
          <Level4 name="Jhon Hancock Center"/>
          <Level4 name="CME group"/>
        </Level3>
        <Level3 name="Naperville"/>
        <Level3 name="Aurora"/>
      </Level2>
    </Level1>

    <Level1 name="United Kingdom">
      <Level2 name="London">
        <Level3 name="Big Ben"/>
        <Level3 name="Heathrow"/>
        <Level3 name="Westminster"/>
      </Level2>
      <Level2 name="Manchester">
        <Level3 name="Old Trafford"/>
      </Level2>
    </Level1>

    <Level1 name="India">
      <Level2 name="Karnataka">
        <Level3 name="Bangalore">
          <Level4 name="CME group"/>
          <Level4 name="MG Road"/>
          <Level4 name="SBIAL"/>
        </Level3>
        <Level3 name="Mysore">
          <Level4 name="Mysore Zoo"/>
        </Level3>
      </Level2>
      <Level2 name="Maharashtra">
        <Level3 name="Mumbai">
          <Level4 name="Juhu"/>
          <Level4 name="Malabar Hills"/>
        </Level3>
        <Level3 name="Pune"/>
      </Level2>
    </Level1>
 
</World>
```

Comment: How are you parsing the XML?

Comment: What format?  Going from root to leaf gives a tree with many branches.

Comment: I have input XML file and need to get the List of all parent's names for given child or get the all the child's name for a given parent.